# It is possible to generate more than one pdf from one source?

Tags: pdf, scripts

I would like to generate some pdf files with a 'for' cycle. The documents have to be very similar, but some variables are different. It is possible to do it with only LaTeX language without external scripting?

Comment: I'm thinking something like a `filecontents` environment inside a for-loop.

Comment: Yes. Give us a sample of what you're after, so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: You should remove the `script` tag if you do not want to use scripting! BTW, to achieve what you want without scripting is, in short, not possible. You will at least need to compile with an option, such as `pdflatex --shell-escape` (that is not exactly scripting, but force you to modify your command, at least).